# xsl select node with child value and pass it as parameter

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some issues to access to the nodes i want.

here is my simplified xml :

```
<chain>
    <components>
        <component>
            <place>2</place>
            <name>bbb</name>
        </component>
        <component>
            <place>1</place>
            <name>aaa</name>
        </component>
        <component>
            <place>3</place>
            <name>ccc</name>
        </component>
    </components>
</chain>
```

the output i want :

```
aaa is connected to bbb
bbb is connected to ccc
```

and my xsl :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="text()"/>

<xsl:template name="writeComponent">
  <xsl:param name="my_component"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$my_component/name"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/chain/components">
        <xsl:for-each select="component">
            <xsl:variable name="nextPlace" select="./place + 1"/>

            <xsl:call-template name="writeComponent">
                <xsl:with-param name="my_component" select='component'/>
            </xsl:call-template> 
            is connected to 
            <xsl:call-template name="writeComponent">
                <xsl:with-param name="my_component" select="component[place = '$nextPlace']"/>
            </xsl:call-template>

       </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to call twite the same template with different nodes in parameter

appreciate any help, thanks

edit : i found the solution for my problem

the calls :

```
<xsl:call-template name="writeComponent">
    <xsl:with-param name="component_param" select="."/>
</xsl:call-template>
is connected to 
<xsl:call-template name="writeComponent">
    <xsl:with-param name="component_param" select="/chain/components/component[place = $nextPlace]"/>
</xsl:call-template>
```

and in the called template, you need to loop in a `<xsl:for-each select="$component_param">`

Comment: Can you add your expected output? Question isn't much clear as, I think, when it is already looping on component, only 1 call-template will suffice..

Comment: i added the desired output and my probleme is i can't pass a node as parameter

Comment: Can you explain the **logic** behind the requested transformation? I don't see how exactly `aaa is connected to bbb`, other than the two being siblings (but then why not also `aaa is connected to ccc`?).

Comment: I use the xml to describe a chain of components like this :
[ aaa -> bbb -> ccc ]

. My output is a text file

BTW : i've found the solution (see my edited question)

Answer (score 0):

In `select="component[place = '$nextPlace']` you would need `select="component[place = $nextPlace]` to have the variable referenced properly. But as the `for-each` processes `component` elements, I don't see how `<xsl:with-param name="component" select='component'/>` could ever select anything in your sample XML. The whole mix of template matching, for-each and calling templates seems questionable, you might want to show us which result you want for the input sample you have, then we can hopefully suggest a cleaner and easier XSLT approach.

Comment: i added the desired output and my probleme is i can't pass a node as parameter